# Zoom in and out of a d3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I made this heatmap. (https://github.com/AlonBenAriVA/D3MapHeatMapSimpleHeat).
Works fine. 
If someone in the community could help me in figuring out how to zoom in and out of it using the mouse scroll and drag with the mouse.
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/avcs06/SVGPanZoom

Answer (score 0):

```
Have a g element in svg and transform it on zoom, instead of svg element:

mapLayer = div.append('svg').attr('id', 'map')
        .attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
        .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed)) // attach zoom handler to svg, but transform g element
        .append("g");

function zoomed() {
  // mapLayer is a g element
  mapLayer.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?